# Python reload can't work

Tags: python, reload

my code is like this:

```
from test.service.settle import query_result

...
reload(query_result) 
from test.service.settle import query_result
rs = query_result(city)
```

That can not work for me.

'query_result()' is a function in settle.py and there are some changes about the 'query_result()'. I hope the code can work by the new change without restarting my project on cloud server.Who can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to reload the module, not the function - `from test.service import settle`, then `reload(settle)` and try `settle.query_result(...)`.

Comment: that still can't work.my original code is like `from test.service.setlle import * ` ,there are lots of functions in the settle.py and I use one of them like `rs = query_result(city)`.I modify my settle.py according to your answer but it can't work without restarting my project on cloud server.

Comment: Then let the lesson here be: don't use wildcard imports.

Answer (score 0):

you should:

```
import test.service.setlle as tss
print tss
from tss import query_result 
query_result(city)
...

#modify query_result
reload(tss)
from tss import query_result
query_result(city)
```

Comment: that still can't work.my original code is like `from test.service.setlle import * ` ,there are lots of functions in the settle.py and I use one of them like `rs = query_result(city)`.I modify my settle.py according to your answer but it can't work without restarting my project on cloud server.

Comment: Follow the whole procedure !!! and replace _from test.service.setlle import *_ by _from tss import *_